# Parsing JSON object using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse the json object using jquery but it is giving me error that cannot get the length of a null object. I am not able to find the reason. Please help me in finding the issue. Here is what i am doing

```
            var slider_images = {
                "image": [
                            {"fname":"1", "caption":"this is 1"},
                            {"fname":"2", "caption":"this is 2"},
                            {"fname":"3", "caption":"this is 3"},
                            {"fname":"4", "caption":"this is 4"},
                            {"fname":"5", "caption":"this is 5"},
                            {"fname":"6", "caption":"this is 6"},
                            {"fname":"7", "caption":"this is 7"},
                            {"fname":"8", "caption":"this is 8"}
                        ]
            };

            var imageObj = $.parseJSON(slider_images.image);
            $.each(imageObj,function() {
                //alert("fname is::"+this['fname']);
                alert("1");
            });
```

I want to get the fname and caption for all the subobjects that fall under image. Please let me know where I am going wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: @Don: that does not work.... Andrew gave me the sol to it below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing JSON means converting a string into a JavaScript object. You already have an object so have nothing to 'parse'.

You can just use your object like this:

```
 $.each(slider_images.image, function() {
        console.log(this);
 });
```

Comment: I kind of notice that but my eyes went to the comma error first

Comment: The comma will also cause problems in some browsers :)

Comment: @Andrew: In what case then i need to parse the JSON? Can you give me a small json object pointed so that I can understand when to parse it and when not...

Comment: @unix_user: Well you parse strings to json such as `{"Greeting": "Hi"}` and stringify objects to jsonstrings `var jsonobj={greating: HiVarOrLitereal}`

Comment: @unix_user If you want to send your object over HTTP for example you would first convert the whole object to a string using `JSON.stringify(obj)`. If you have a string and want it turned back into an object, use `JSON.parse(str)` or your jQuery version. The JSON string _looks_ like an object `'{"a":1,"b":2}'`, but it's a string until you parse it. JSON is useful because you can send objects as strings. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you very much for to-the point explanation. This thing got clear now...